# How to switch views from barbuttonitem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have an overlay in which I've created a toolbar containing a done button.
The name of the selector for done button is doneButtonPressed.

Now when I click done button, how do I get a new nib view? Let's us assume I created a nib named TestViewController.

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed {

//What goes here?

}
```

Comment: Do you want a temporary modal view, or a brand new view?

Comment: What kind of navigationcontroller you are using ?

Comment: I would like a brand new view, and remember that I don't want to use a navigation stack. The bar button is on a toolbar overlay that appears when I access the camera. When I click done I will direct the view to a TableViewController. So you can imagine what I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate a UIViewController from a nib you can use the following line of code:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerName = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:(NSString *) bundle:(NSBundle *)];
```

Then you can present the view modally with:

```
[self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)];
```

Now if you are using a storyboard, then you could just instantiate a view controller from a storyboard object.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could turn your view into a "container view". To do that you will need to create subviews and then just switch them out. I did this when I wanted a menu to control a different view.

```
[self.view insertSubview:(view you want to insert) atIndex:0];
```

Then when you want to switch it out:

```
[[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:(view you want to replace with) atIndex:0];
```

EDITED

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

- (void)doneButtonPressed {

SkipQViewController *skipQ = [[SkipQViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Name" bundle:bundleName];
[self presentModalViewController:skipQ animated:YES];
}
```

If that does not work try using: `SkipQViewController *skipQ = [[SkipQViewController alloc] init];` to instantiate your view controller.

-EDIT-

Instantiate the view controller as such: `SkipQViewController *skipQ = (SkipQViewController *)[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sqvc" bundle:nil];`

Comment: No luck with that either. What's the general format used to bring up a new view from a barbuttonitem? I have a feeling it's something rather easy but I feel I am overlooking the simple solutions.

Comment: You can have the button segue to another view controller, or you could have the button bring up a view controller modally. Another option is to present a popover view, however I don't think that is what you want. You need to implement an action on the done button. Hook up the done button to an IBAction method.

Comment: I haven't made the button through IB, it is made programatically because my overlay and the toolbar overlay on the main overlay was made programatically. So the barbuttonitem was made programatically too. Forget all this, assume you had a made a barbuttonitem programatically. You have a nib named testviewcontroller. What would  your lines of code be to bring up testviewcontroller from BBI?

Comment: The selector is faulty when due to the : you've added after Pressed. I click on the button and it stays in selected mode(as if it's held) and it crashes. Here's the error log: SecondViewController doneButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16abf0
2012-07-31 16:28:57.339 [2440:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController doneButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16abf0'.                     Now if I remove the colon and run it, the done button responds(NSlog test) but doesn't switch views.

Comment: Sorry for the colon, that was a mistake. If the done button responds according to NSLog placed inside doneButtonPressed method, that means the view controller is being instantiated incorrectly. Can you give more details about your project, maybe post some of the code? It would be helpful to see how you are instantiating everything.

Comment: The .h and .m files :  http://pastebin.com/h64y1WzK,
 http://pastebin.com/gAHqGK09

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Instead of instantiating a UIViewController you should instantiate a SkipQViewController since you have subclassed it in another file. I will update part of the code in my answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand, wouldn't instantiating Skiqviwcontroller be redundant as I already have done so? Can you edit the code and post the paste bin web link here please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason for this is because you have created a class called SkipQViewController (I can see this because you have imported it in your .h header file). Because that class is what controls your view, you want to make sure your object is an instance of it instead of UIViewController. Make sure your xib for the view is linked to SkipQViewController. The new paste bin: http://pastebin.com/d3wvJZkM

Comment: I somewhat understand the logic, but now I get the error "Incompatible  pointer types initialising 'SkipQViewController *' with an expression of the type 'UIViewController *'. I thought the pointers were taken care of?

Comment: Do you have a class called SkipQViewController? Also for the nib do you have it's class set to SkipQViewController?

Comment: Absolutely. One question, I don't understand why you're bringing up the nib into the picture. Of course, I do want  the barbuttonitem to take me to a new view (sqvc.nib). I've imported files accordingly into the appropriate class for that to occur. Remember I've made the toolbar and its contents programmatically?  All of this is really odd, I've used pretty much the same method word 4 word as you've prescribed before, but that was for a button on a nib, for which I've used the IBAction method. I really don't understand how using it for a programatically made uitoolbar barbuttonitem is failing.

Comment: Well the error you got tells me that your programmatically made bar button item is not the problem. That is working fine. The problem is loading your sqvc.nib. The only thing I can think of is that either there is something wrong with your .m/.h file for SkipQViewController or that your .nib doesn't reference SkipQViewController. Anyway, I have one more suggestion for you to try before you change anything. I have added the line of code to my answer for you to test it out.

Comment: No luck with that either. I give up, I'm going to use a regular button on the overlay instead instead of the toolbar. I'll see how the UIButton works out. You're right, the buttons are working. But the method itself is as good as useless. I'll give up on the barbuttonitems.